# Python realtime subprocess output and Progressbar in PyQT5

Tags: python, pyqt5, subprocess

I want to show a progress bar on PyQt5 while a subprocess operation takes place. I have looked into all the answers to get realtime output of a subprocess command. However, nothing worked. In my case, the subprocess output gets buffered and then gives it out together and that is why the progressbar jumps directly from 0 to 100%. What am I doing wrong? The subprocess command is completed in 5 steps which is given as output and based on the steps I am counting the percentage of the task completed.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QProgressBar, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QThread, pyqtSignal
import time
import subprocess


class MyThread(QThread):
    change_value = pyqtSignal(int)

    def run(self):
        cnt = 0
        cmdline = 'atprogram -t atmelice -d ATxmega128D4 -i PDI -cl 1MHz -tv 3.3 chiperase erase -ee program -c -fl -fs -lb -ee -f Hello.elf --verify'
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmdline, shell=True,
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        while True:
            line = p.stdout.readlines()
            #print (line)
            cnt += 100/5
            self.change_value.emit(cnt)
            if not line and cnt==100:
                break
        
class Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "PyQt5 ProgressBar"
        self.top = 200
        self.left = 500
        self.width = 300
        self.height = 100
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.progressbar = QProgressBar()
        self.progressbar.setRange(0,100)
        #self.progressbar.setMaximum(100)
        self.progressbar.setStyleSheet("QProgressBar {border: 2px solid grey;border-radius:8px;padding:1px}"
                                       "QProgressBar::chunk {background:yellow}")
        vbox.addWidget(self.progressbar)
        self.button = QPushButton("Start Progressbar")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.startProgressBar)
        self.button.setStyleSheet('background-color:yellow')
        vbox.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.show()

    def startProgressBar(self):
        self.thread = MyThread()
        self.progressbar.setValue(0)
        self.thread.change_value.connect(self.setProgressVal)
        self.thread.start()
        self.button.setEnabled(False)

    def setProgressVal(self, val):
        self.progressbar.setValue(val)
        if val == 100:
            self.button.setEnabled(True)


App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Output:

```
[b'Firmware check OK\r\n', b'Chiperase completed successfully\r\n', b'Erasing eeprom...\r\n', b'Erased eeprom completed successfully.\r\n', b'Programming and verification completed successfully.\r\n']

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\mohammad\Desktop\Test.py", line 23
    self.change_value.emit(cnt)
DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type float).  Implicit conversion to integers using __int__ is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python.
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

Comment: Could you show the output in the CMD if you run `atprogram -t atmelice -d ATxmega128D4 -i PDI -cl 1MHz -tv 3.3 chiperase erase -ee program -c -fl -fs -lb -ee -f Hello.elf --verify`? I want to take it as a reference for a possible answer.

Comment: @eyllanesc 
CMD output:

Firmware check OK\n
Chiperase completed successfully\n
Erasing eeprom...\n
Erased eeprom completed successfully\n
Programming and verification completed successfully.\n

Comment: you could put in your post the complete log **without clipping** it to be able to analyze it easily

Comment: @eyllanesc I have updated my post